# SPFx Play HTML5 Video dynamically on a webpart

Tags: reactjs, typescript, html5-video, sharepoint-online, spfx

We are developing a webpart

1. That has a textbox where we supply a Video URL
2. This would fetch the Video URL from a SharePoint list on button click and set the SRC of the Video
   Element, Below is the code

   ```
   function textFieldChanged(newValue: string){ 

   let vidplay = document.getElementById('VidPlayer');
   let source = document.createElement('source');
   source.setAttribute('src', newValue);
   vidplay.appendChild(source);
   vidplay.load();
   vidplay.play();

   sp.web.currentUser.get().then((user: ISiteUserInfo) => {

     console.log("user", user);
     const userId: number = user.Id;

     sp.web.lists.getByTitle(videoList).
       items.select("ID", "User/ID", "VideoURL")
       .expand("User")
       .filter(`VideoURL eq '${decodeURIComponent(newValue)}' and User/ID eq '${userId}'`)
       .top(1)
       .get()
       .then((videos: IVideoEntry[]) => {
         console.log("Videos", videos);

         // Did we find a video?
         if (videos.length > 0) {
           //Update the record
           const video: IVideoEntry = videos[0];
           console.log("We found the video", video);

           alert(videoRef.current.currentTime);

         }
       });
   });
   ```

   }

**Video Player Element**

```
<div>
      <video
        id="VidPlayer"
        ref={videoRef}
        style={{ width: elementWidth }}
        src={txtParam}
      //controls
      ></video>< br/>

      <TextField id="txtVideoURL" onChange={(ev,newValue)=> {txtParam=newValue}}/> 

      <DefaultButton text="Submit" onClick={()=>{textFieldChanged(txtParam)}}/>

</div>
```

Read a lot of articles pertaining to the same, however unable to use .play() and .load() which is required to load the video element and then play.

Not sure how this needs to be done in SPFx and would really appreciate if anyone here could help us out.

Please let me know if any other detail is required

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

@Vivek,

As it's a React project, I'd like to suggest you use ref instead of id.

```
private video_ref: React.RefObject<HTMLVideoElement>;
 constructor(props: IPlayerProps) {
    super(props);    
    this.videoRef= React.createRef();

  }
```

And we can get its instance in `textFieldChanged` method like below:

```
private textFieldChanged(newValue: string) {
    let vidplay = this.videoRef.current;
    let source = document.createElement('source');
    source.setAttribute('src', newValue);
    vidplay.appendChild(source);
    vidplay.load();
    vidplay.play();
  }
```

You may also use other react video controls.

- https://github.com/CookPete/react-player
- https://github.com/video-react/video-react

BR

Comment: Appreciate the help :)

I am still facing issues , Since you're one of the popular members here , would you mind moving this conversation to chat as it would be easier to explain there?